# Ember.js: HtmlBars and the Handlebars.compile command

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I get the following error when running my app:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile`.
```

It is related to this piece of code:

```
var CarouselView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view view.itemsView}}'),
    elementId: 'carousel',
    contentBinding: 'content',
    ...
```

There is already an issue related about this problem on ember.js github: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10265

However I added `ember-template-compiler` to my package.json and got the same error again.

I did:
`npm install --save-dev ember-template-compiler`

Here are my package.json devDependencies:

```
 "ember-cli": "0.1.10",
 "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.0",
 "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
 "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
 "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^0.6.0",
 "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
 "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
 "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.0",
 "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.7.2",
 "ember-cli-simple-auth-cookie-store": "^0.7.2",
 "ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2": "^0.7.2",
 "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
 "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12",
 "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
 "ember-template-compiler": "^1.8.0",
 "express": "^4.8.5",
 "glob": "^4.0.5"
```

Reference: the `ember-template-compiler` [github page](https://github.com/toranb/ember-template-compiler)

Anyone has experience with HtmlBars and the compile command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to compile HTMLBars template on the client, however adding `ember-template-compiler` in `package.json` only enables precompilation of HTMLBars templates server-side.

To enable client-side compilation, you should add `ember-template-compiler` to the `bower.json`, e.g. (use appropriate version)

```
"ember-template-compiler": "http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"
```

and then include it in `Brocfile.js`,

```
app.import('bower_components/ember-template-compiler/index.js');
```

Comment: That did the trick! However why this is never documented on the internet? I create a Github issue about the eventual documentation for this.

Comment: Could you please add the link to that issue?

Comment: Background info: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html

Comment: Hi this is still ocurring for me despite following the instructions above. link to my issue ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240763/ember-js-please-load-ember-template-compiler-js-prior-to-calling-compile

Comment: hey which brocfilte you are taking .plz help

Answer (score 16):

Since Ember.js 1.10 template compiler is part of Ember, so all you have to do to compile templates in client side is to add following line in your Brocfile:

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

Comment: where to add these line when i find the Brocfile in Ember 2.0 i got 3 file   /home/nesh/paint/node_modules/ember-cli-content-security-policy/Brocfile.js    And the One is /home/nesh/paint/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/Brocfile.js

Comment: i was try add line in these 2 file  but i got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

For my views, I just created template files for them.  To use your case as an example, I would create app/templates/views/carousel.hbs:

```
{{view view.itemsView}}
```

Then CarouselView becomes:

```
var CarouselView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'views/carousel',
  elementId: 'carousel',
  contentBinding: 'content',
  ...
```

This way you don't have to give the client the template compiler.  Should result in better performance and a smaller payload for the client to download.